# PHP table display from database airport board

Tags: php, html, sql-server, display

I am looking for a way to display my table in such way that it display certain amount of records in the database and after few seconds it move to next page to display other records.

Let's say I want to display table from database have 20 record but I want to show only 10 records and after sometimes page move or like animation to second page show the rest of the records f.e airport board thanks.

```
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    echo "<tr class='alt'><td>";    
    echo "<img src = '".$row['Image']."' height='100' width='100'/>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Student_Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Req_Time']->format('D M d  H:i:s ');
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></center>";
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your questions here.

Comment: You could render two tables, and then use JavaScript to show one at a time, on a timer system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery Ajax to submit a post request that will return the table you want. Using setTimeout o setInterval you can control when to refresh the table. And you can send the variables limit and offset to use in your query to show only the info you want.

Check the library http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: can you give me example please? i tried to use ajax to submit form and for some reason it didn't work thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11847905)

Comment: @kittykittybangbang: it's a brief answer to a broad question. Answers that do not require clarification usually follow from clear and concise questions.